# iTunes pauses and does random things when my headphones move

Tags: itunes, audio, headphones

I am using iTunes on Mac.  I suppose there might be a problem with my headphones and it is sending random commands to the computer.  When I move my head, my iTunes pauses and sometimes it goes to a different podcast.  Is there anything I can do to simply disable the headphones from controlling iTunes?

Comment: Are these headphones specifically designed to control iPods/iPhones, or just a generic set of headphones?

Comment: They are generic and cheap, but they have volume controls on them.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is related to the microswitch located at the very bottom inside the speaker jack. Whenever you get this problem, make sure your speaker cable is fully inserted into the speaker jack. Even the slightest depress on the microswitch can create interference, causing itunes to start and random songs to start playing. I also recommend bringing your computer to an apple store and getting the speaker jack cleaned, since dust or other contaminants can cause this issue. They can also make sure that nothing is wrong with your microswitch. A friend of mine had to have his motherboard replaced due to a faulty microswitch. This is covered by warrantee as long as your mac isn't too old to be covered.

link: https://discussions.apple.com/message/15803561#15803561

Comment: Thanks, this is my work computer, so I don't want to bring it to the store.  Is there any way for me to clean it myself?  Can I just disable this functionality?